# How to reduce size of text-input in datepicker?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

[image]

I have datepicker and i am using bootstrap, i want to find a way to reduce its width. It seem to fill my browser as large. Here is my code below for this logic.

```
 <!---DatePicker
   ----> 
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
 <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="from" placeholder="startdate"/>
   <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
   <input type="text" class= "input-sm form-control" placeholder="enddate"/>
     </div>
  </div><br>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code for your section i just use bootstrap `col-**-*` classes.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid justify-content-start">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-12">
      <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
        <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="from" placeholder="startdate"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
        <input type="text" class= "input-sm form-control" placeholder="enddate"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will work for you.

Thank you...

Comment: How do i do that, im trying to find accept answer here.